# Can't find ELF header

Tags: python-3.x, sdk, elf

I'm trying to use the zwo asi python bindings library (available [here](https://github.com/python-zwoasi/python-zwoasi)) on a Debian machine.

To do so, I downloaded the SDK from [zwo's website](https://astronomy-imaging-camera.com/software-drivers) (the Mac & Linux version), placed the ASICamera2.h file in the `/usr/include` and ran the commands written in the README.txt in the lib folder of the archive.
I effectively get the "200" answer when using the command :

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb
```

Then I created an environement variable in `/etc/profile` called ZWO_ASI_LIB which refers to the ASICamera2.h file I talked about earlier.

Here's the code of my python script (it's not the complete code, but the part that causes the problem) :

```
import os
import sys
import zwoasi

def startCamera():
    env_filename = os.getenv('ZWO_ASI_LIB')

    if env_filename:
        zwoasi.init(env_filename)
    else:
        print("Error : Library not found")
        sys.exit(1)

startCamera()
```

When I launch it in my terminal via the `python3 x.py` command, I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 87, in <module>
    startCamera()
  File "x.py", line 21, in startCamera
    zwoasi.init(env_filename)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zwoasi/__init__.py", line 821, in init
    zwolib = c.cdll.LoadLibrary(library_file)
  File "usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/include/ASICamera2.h: invalid ELF header
```

I guess I am meant to have an ELF header somewhere (.elf file ?) for the SDK library, but I haven't been able to find it. It could be that I am just not refering to the right file, but according to [the documentation given on the zwo's website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW5no.png), the file I put in my environement variable is the header.
Also, I didn't really understand what they meant by "Under Linux the dynamic and static library: ASICamera2.so, ASICamera2.a"

The camera I'm using is the ASI178MC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `OSError: /usr/include/ASICamera2.h: invalid ELF header`

You have told your runtime environment that `ASICamera2.h` is the name of a shared library it should be loading (using `dlopen` on).

But `ASICamera2.h` is `C` header (text) file defining the *API* for that library, not the library itself.

Instead you should point Python to a *shared library* (which is likely also part of the SDK you downloaded). Usually shared libraries end with `.so`. Documentation you pointed to says that the library is named `ASICamera2.so`.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow! Thank you verry much for your answer :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem ^^' I didn't know about that...